# Pwa studio showing {{#pageTypeNonce}}{{#webpackChunks}}{{/webpackChunks}} {{/pageTypeNonce}} at footer

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio, upward-connector

I've installed magento 2.4.5 with pwa studio + upward connector, but when i access the frontend, there is a text was echo in the footer {{#pageTypeNonce}}{{#webpackChunks}}{{/webpackChunks}} {{/pageTypeNonce}}

[image]

anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Hi, I am too having this on the frontend, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Same bug.

Try to install magento module
https://github.com/swissup/module-upward-connector

Answer (score 0):

```
veniaResponse:
  resolver: conditional
  when:
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: ^/(graphql|rest|media)(/|$)
      use: veniaProxy
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: ^/(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|manifest\.json)
      use: staticFromRoot
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: (js|json|png|jpg|gif|svg|ico|css|txt)
      use: veniaStatic
  default: veniaAppShell
staticFromRoot:
  inline:
    status: 200
    headers:
      resolver: inline
      inline:
        content-type: contentTypeFromExtension
        cache-control:
          when:
            - matches: env.NODE_ENV
              pattern: production
              use:
                inline: 'public, max-age=604800'
          default:
            inline: 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    body:
      resolver: file
      parse:
        inline: text
      encoding:
        inline: binary
      file:
        resolver: template
        engine: mustache
        provide:
          filename: request.url.pathname
        template:
          resolver: inline
          inline: './venia-static/{{ filename }}'
contentTypeFromExtension:
  when:
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^ico$
      use:
        inline: image/x-icon
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^txt$
      use:
        inline: text/plain
    - matches: fileExtension
      pattern: ^json$
      use:
        inline: application/json
  default:
    inline: text/html
fileExtension:
  resolver: conditional
  when:
    - matches: request.url.pathname
      pattern: \.(.*)$
      use: $match.$1
  default:
    inline: ''
veniaProxy:
  resolver: proxy
  target: env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL
  ignoreSSLErrors:
    when:
      - matches: env.NODE_ENV
        pattern: production
        use:
          inline: false
    default:
      inline: true
veniaPageType:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    data:
      resolver: computed
      type:
        resolver: inline
        inline: pageType
      additional:
        - type: product
          fetch: '__typename,id'
        - type: cms_page
          fetch: identifier
        - type: category
          fetch: uid
veniaPageTypeNonce:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    nonce:
      resolver: computed
      type:
        resolver: inline
        inline: pageTypeNonce
veniaWebpackChunks:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    scripts:
      resolver: computed
      type:
        resolver: inline
        inline: webpackChunks
veniaAppShell:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    status:
      resolver: inline
      inline: 200
    headers:
      resolver: inline
      inline:
        content-type:
          inline: text/html
        cache-control:
          inline: s-maxage=60
        content-security-policy: veniaSecurityHeaders.content-security-policy
        strict-transport-security: veniaSecurityHeaders.strict-transport-security
        x-content-type-options: veniaSecurityHeaders.x-content-type-options
        x-frame-options: veniaSecurityHeaders.x-frame-options
        x-xss-protection: veniaSecurityHeaders.x-xss-protection
    body:
      resolver: template
      engine: mustache
      provide:
        pageType: veniaPageType.data
        pageTypeNonce: veniaPageTypeNonce.nonce
        webpackChunks: veniaWebpackChunks.scripts
      template:
        resolver: file
        file:
          resolver: inline
          inline: ./index.html
veniaStatic:
  resolver: directory
  directory:
    resolver: inline
    inline: .
veniaStaticIncludes:
  resolver: directory
  directory:
    resolver: inline
    inline: ./venia-static
veniaSecurityHeaders:
  resolver: inline
  inline:
    content-security-policy:
      resolver: template
      engine: mustache
      provide:
        backend: env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL
        pageTypeNonce: veniaPageTypeNonce.nonce
      template:
        resolver: conditional
        when:
          - matches: env.NODE_ENV
            pattern: development
            use:
              inline: ''
          - matches: env.SCRIPT_NAME
            pattern: .*\.php$
            use:
              inline: ' script-src http: https: {{ backend }}{{#pageTypeNonce}} ''nonce-{{ pageTypeNonce }}''{{/pageTypeNonce}}; style-src ''self'' blob: https: ''unsafe-inline'' {{ backend }}; img-src data: http: https:; object-src ''none''; base-uri ''none''; child-src ''self''; font-src ''self'' fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src assets.braintreegateway.com *.google.com *.youtube.com *.youtu.be *.vimeo.com '
        default:
          inline: ' script-src http: https: {{ backend }}; style-src ''self'' blob: https: ''unsafe-inline'' {{ backend }}; img-src data: http: https:; object-src ''none''; base-uri ''none''; child-src ''self''; font-src ''self'' fonts.gstatic.com; frame-src assets.braintreegateway.com *.google.com *.youtube.com *.youtu.be *.vimeo.com '
    strict-transport-security:
      inline: max-age=31536000
    x-content-type-options:
      inline: nosniff
    x-frame-options:
      inline: SAMEORIGIN
    x-xss-protection:
      inline: 1; mode=block
status: veniaResponse.status
headers: veniaResponse.headers
body: veniaResponse.body
```

try replace this in dist/upward.yml

Comment: It doesn't fixed the issue. Instead giving {"error":"No definition for env.MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL"}